# Implementing Horizontal Recyclerview from centre and changing width of recyclerview by right and left swipe

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a horizontal recyclerview that scrolls from left to right. I want to show the recyclerview from centre with only four items firstly and its first item got a right arrow, the thing i want is when i click on right arrow recycler view should show all the items and by swiping back to left recycler view should come to its previous position with first item of arrow.

Below pic is recycler view that start from centre and have right arrow

[image]

The view by clicking on arrow should be

[image]

and the recyclerview I made is

[image]

This is recyclerview xml code

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerIcons"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/top"
        android:orientation="horizontal"/>
```

This is Adapter code

```
@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.icon_item, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view,mListner);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {

    holder.circleImageView.setImageResource(iconsModelList.get(position).getImageView());

}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return iconsModelList.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    CircleImageView circleImageView;

    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView, OnItemClickListener listener) {
        super(itemView);
        circleImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.player_recycler_icon);

    }
}
```

This is recyclerview implementation

```
 recyclerViewIcons = findViewById(R.id.recyclerIcons);

    List<IconsModel> list = new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(new IconsModel(R.drawable.ic_rightarrow));
    list.add(new IconsModel(R.drawable.newlock));
    list.add(new IconsModel(R.drawable.screenautorotate));
    list.add(new IconsModel(R.drawable.newlock));
    list.add(new IconsModel(R.drawable.screenautorotate));
    list.add(new IconsModel(R.drawable.newlock));
    list.add(new IconsModel(R.drawable.screenautorotate));
    list.add(new IconsModel(R.drawable.newlock));
    list.add(new IconsModel(R.drawable.newlock));

    IconsAdapter iconsAdapter = new IconsAdapter(list, this);
    LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
    layoutManager.setOrientation(RecyclerView.HORIZONTAL);
    layoutManager.setReverseLayout(true);
    recyclerViewIcons.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
    recyclerViewIcons.setAdapter(iconsAdapter);
    iconsAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    iconsAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new IconsAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
        @SuppressLint("UseCompatLoadingForDrawables")
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(int position) {
            CircleImageView imageView = findViewById(R.id.player_recycler_icon);
            if (position == 0) {

                //arrow code will be here

           }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why do you have to use `setReverseLayout` ? Why not just insert the rest of the items from index 0 and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` . Initially have only 3 items and on click of Array add those items .

Comment: By default items scroll from left to right and by using setReverseLayout items will scroll from right to left.